# Parse error in pattern in my little program

Tags: haskell, parse-error

```
left :: [String]->[Char]->Char
left [] _ = []
left (x:xs) (head xs) = x    -- it says error at head
```

I used proper parenthesis but still taking parse error.By the way, I m trying to get previous element in list such as `[["A"],["B"],["C"],["D"],["E"]]` . Maybe I have some other mistakes. Pls correct me .

2nd question is how can pick previous elements previous indexed character. Such as giving function this list [["J","O","H","N"],["A","L","I","C","E"]] and "C" , I want to expect to get "H". I mean "C" is 2nd element 4th index and "H" is previous elements 3rd index. Thnx in advance

Comment: `head xs` is an expression, not a pattern. In a pattern you can only use constructors like `[]` and `:`, and variables.

Comment: Right now it is vvery unclear what you are trying to achieve, please show some 8n and output​. If you want to find out about the error ghc is giving, take each line of your definition put it in ghci and ask its signature with `:t`, after you have fixed the error @chi mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you well, you need a function which find a character in a list of `String`, and return the character of the preceding string at the preceding index.

Something like:

```
f ["JOHN", "ALICE"] 'C' == 'H'
```

First you need to know that `Char` literals are delimited with simple quotes in Haskell (`'A'`), and `String` literals with double quotes (`"ABC"`).

Since in Haskell `String` is an alias for `[Char]`, `"ABC"` is equivalent to `['A', 'B', 'C']`.

This said, in Haskell you can't define a function like this: `f a a = stuff`. GHC will complain that `a` is defined multiple times.
So to check if two arguments have some property, you need [guard patterns](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#pattern-guards).

So I would write your first function like this:

```
left :: [String] -> String -> String
left [] _ = ""
left [x] _ = ""
left (x1:x2:xs) str
    | x2 == str = x1
    | otherwise = left (x2:xs) str
```

For your second question:

```
import Data.List

f :: [String] -> Char -> Maybe Char
f [] _ = Nothing
f [a] _ = Nothing
f (x1:x2:xs) c
    | Just i <- elemIndex c x2 = Just $ x1 !! (i-1)
    | otherwise = f (x2:xs) c
```

Notes:

- `left` should also return a `Maybe String` in case `str` isn't found or is first.
- `f` doesn't check if `x1` is actually long enough
- Usually in Haskell, the list parameter is last, to permit [currying](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying).

EDIT:

A somewhat more clever approach with `zip` (in module `Data.List`).

```
f :: [String] -> Char -> Maybe Char
f [] _ = Nothing
f [_] _ = Nothing
f (x1:"":xs) c = f xs c
f (x1:x2:xs) c = f' (zip x1 (tail x2))
    where f' [] = f (x2:xs) c
          f' ((a,b):l) = if b == c then a else f' l
```

This version won't crash. It will return the first character which satisfies "being mth character in nth string, while the (m+1)th character in (n+1)th string" is `c`. The result will be wrapped in a `Maybe` (`Just 'H'`). Otherwise, it returns `Nothing` (`Maybe` is roughly the nullable type for Haskell).

`zip` is a function which merges two lists in one list of pairs:

```
zip ['a', 'b', 'c'] [1, 2] == [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

The size of the resulting list is the one of the smallest. So in the example, what happens is:

```
zip "JOHN" (tail "ALICE") == [('J','L'), ('O', 'I'), ('H', 'C'), ('N', 'E')]
```

You then just have to check is the second character is the searched one, and then return the first character of the pair.

Comment: its really nice answer, thank you very much 1st. I wonder 1 more advance stage in same question : What if i have same characters in same elements in my input such as [["C","C","C"],["D","D","D"]] . Does algorithm above fails in both questions?

Comment: In addition I get those errors for 2nd code:
 
ex.hs:5:17: error: Variable not in scope: elemIndex :: Char -> String -> Maybe Int
ex.hs:5:35: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe Char’ with actual type ‘Char’
    • In the expression: (x1 !! (i - 1))
      In an equation for ‘f’:
          f (x1 : x2 : xs) c
            | Just i <- elemIndex c x2 = (x1 !! (i - 1))
            | otherwise = f (x2 : xs) c

Comment: Oh yeah this must be fixed now (I added a `Just` constructor and an import for `elemIndex`). You can look for Haskell terms with [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) when you don't remember the signature of a function or the package containing it.

Comment: For your first question, I guess yes, it will fail. we can think of more clever approach with things like `zip`. Hoogle for the doc :). It takes two lists and create a list of tuples. `zip ['a', 'b'] [1, 2, 3] == [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]. In your case, you could use `zip list (tail list)`. I will add this to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To have access to the "previous" list element, you have to use a different recursion. E.g.

```
foo []  = baseCase
foo [x] = onlyOneElement x
foo (x1:x2:xs) = use x1 x2 (foo (x2:xs))
```

When calling `foo [1,2,3,4,5]`, you get access to `x1=1, x2=2`. When you recurse, you will get access to `x1=2, x2=3`, and so on. So, you can consider `x2` to be the "current" element, and `x1` to be the previous one.

Comment: I understand the idea except "use" thing. is there any way to keep track of indexes while recursion going on ? I mean what if I want to make even/odd checks on previous elemtns in if condition ?

Comment: If you need even/odd index information, you can pass an additional boolean telling whether we are at an even index. Then, every time we recurse, we negate that boolean, so that it continuously flips between true and false, as we want.